# How to play a sound after timer ends and no input has been given by the user?

Tags: python, audio, timer, formatting

So I'm currently trying to program a math quiz, where the user has a set amount of time to solve a simple equation in their head. Depending on the answer a different sound gets played, either a 'successful sound' or 'failed sound'. That part works perfectly. But I'm looking for a way to play the 'failed sound' after the timer runs out and no input has been given. By the way, I'm new to python and programming in general and would like to know how to correctly format my code, to increase readability and conform to programming standards.

This is my code:

````
from playsound import playsound
from threading import Timer

lownumber = 10
highnumber = 30
randnumber1 = random.randrange(lownumber, highnumber)
randnumber2 = random.randrange(lownumber, highnumber)
question = randnumber1, '*', randnumber2
timeout = 7
prompt = "You have %d seconds to choose the correct answer... " % timeout
t = Timer(timeout, print, ["Sorry, times up"])

print(question)
t.start()
answer = int(input(prompt))
t.cancel()


if answer == randnumber1*randnumber2:
    playsound('successful_sound.wav')
else:
    playsound('failed_sound.wav')```
````